# JQuery get the rest of the element's class name that starts with string "whatever-"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have js that caches classes that's name starts with "whatever-",

```
$('[class^="whatever-"], [class*=" whatever-"]')
```

but what I want now to do is get the rest of the name, for example in case of "whatever-9" I want to get "9", I don't know how to do it, can you help me?

Comment: `$(this).attr("class").substr("whatever-".length)` within the function applying to that, just a while guess :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
var check = "whatever-";         
    $('[class^="whatever-"], [class*=" whatever-"]').each(function () {    
        // Get array of class names   
        var cls = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');       
        for (var i = 0; i < cls.length; i++) {
            // Iterate over the class and log it if it matches
            if (cls[i].indexOf(check) > -1) {        
                console.log(cls[i].slice(check.length, cls[i].length));
            }       
        }    
    });
```

This should also work for the case when there is more than 1 class. There may be cleaner ways of doing this by using `filter` method and a bit of `regex`

### **[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/XwVaF/3/)**

A little cleaner using `map`

```
var check = "whatever-";
$('[class^="whatever-"], [class*=" whatever-"]').each(function () {
    var className = this.className;

    var cls = $.map(this.className.split(' '), function (val, i) {
        if (val.indexOf(check) > -1) {
            return val.slice(check.length, val.length)
        }
    });

    console.log(cls.join(' '));
});
```

**[Map demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/XwVaF/4/)**

Comment: Yeap, it should work as well, but I think the best solution wrote "Sergio", that is "cleaner" code

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there are better ways, but this works. Check the console.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XwVaF/2/)**

```
$('[class^="whatever-"], [class*=" whatever-"]').each(function () {
    var classname = this.className;
    var classsparts = classname.split('whatever-');
    var result = classsparts[1]
    console.log(result);
});
```

This is assuming you just have one class in the elements you are targeting with your selectors.

Comment: nice one.. `var classname = this.className` will be better I think. :)

Comment: Good point @Mr_Green! then is JS almost all the way. Edited the answer.

Comment: Sergio, your solution works fine if it is only 1 class on element, but if there are multiple class names, console returns other class names those are set after "whatever-"

Comment: @Irakli, exactly. I wrote that also. Sushanth had a nice answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Or if you like a little regular expression I would use this because hey it's just one line.

```
$("*").filter(function(){ return /whatever-.+/.test( $(this).attr("class") ) } );
```