# jQuery work with random classes of siblings to perfom actions on them?

Tags: jquery, class

We have a ton of siblings, which cannot be put into separate Div's. They are divided by random class names in a few different groups.

To mark the first one of a group is easy in jQuery, but how can I get the groups class names and use what I've got to work with it?

This is how it could look like

---

UPDATE: The groups are totally mixed up. Like a card deck.

The end result is preferably, getting all the groups with jQuery. Next jQuery has now all the data of what groups exist. And then it marks the first one (in the DOM order) of this group.

The thing is that they also should stay mixed as they are.

---

With groups are meant: Different classes. One group is defined by Divs of the same group class.

---

```
<div class="group-456 fav"></div>
<div class="group-855 fav"></div>
<div class="group-143 fav"></div>
<!-- unnecessary line break -->
<div class="group-616 fav"></div>
<div class="group-143 fav"></div>
<div class="group-855 fav"></div>
<!-- unnecessary line break -->
<div class="group-855 fav"></div>
<div class="group-616 fav"></div>
<div class="group-456 fav"></div>
<!-- unnecessary line break -->
<div class="group-616 fav"></div>
<div class="group-143 fav"></div>
<div class="group-456 fav"></div>
```

This is what I have put together

```
var detect = $('div').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('class');
});
console.log(detect);

$('.fav').first().css({background: 'lightcoral'});
```

This is from stackoverflow

```
var check = "group-";
$('div').each(function(){
    var className = this.className;

    var cls = $.map(this.className.split(' '), function (val, i) {
        if (val.indexOf(check) > -1) {
            return val.slice(check.length, val.length)
        }
    });

    console.log(cls.join(' '));
});

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159121/jquery-get-the-rest-of-the-elements-class-name-that-starts-with-string-whateve
```

Comment: so what is the desired output you want?

Comment: Please provide feedback on the desired output as it's currently open to interpretation.

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far. I am into a bit over a year in development and very excited about stack overflow (this is my first question).

I updated the question.

Comment: "The first one" in what sense? The first element in the "groups divided by an empty row"? You edited your question too many times, first, you need to know what you want, then you need to ask for it very specific. You probably want to make a group based on each "empty row" separated group. Probably, who knows...

Comment: Sorry for that. I meant the first item (that appears) of each group.

Comment: You probably want to keep the elements as they are, but you need a "separator" for them. You can not just check for a new line element or some irregular node type, as long as it's not consistent. You can check by using the "nextSibling" or "nextElementSibling" but this is tricky and inconsistent.

Comment: Hey @n1kkou, please excuse me for asking you again: What would you do in this situation? I’m a js-rookie and have no idea what to do. I’m totally overwhelmed.

Comment: it is difficult to group the elements in this context. Is there any pattern in your HTML elements, like grouping the elements starting from a specific class name like "group-616", or they are totally random? Or, do you want to group them in sets of "x" elements, like groups of 3 elements? I'm really confused about your HTML structure and what/how you really want to group them.

Comment: yes, every element starts with the "group-" string or at least has the class of "fav" or are all div siblings in a container with a known class. Then after the program knows how many different groups inside this container exist, the goal is to mark the first item of each class and leave the other items of the same class "unmarked" so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the DIVs are in group order, you can loop through each div and compare the group with the previous div's group value - if they are different, it's a new group:

```
var grp = "";
$(".fav").each(function() {
    var thisgrp = getgroup(this);
    if (grp != thisgrp) $(this).addClass("markit")
    grp = thisgrp;
})
```

where `getgroup()` is your existing code to extract the group ID (with an extra `return cls;`)

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/25twmquy/ and snippet below

```js
function getgroup(el) {
  var check = "group-";
  var className = el.className;

  var cls = $.map(className.split(' '), function(val, i) {
    if (val.indexOf(check) > -1) {
      return val.slice(check.length, val.length)
    }
  });

  return cls.join(" ");
}

var grp = "";
$(".fav").each(function() {
  var thisgrp = getgroup(this);
  if (grp != thisgrp) $(this).addClass("markit")
  grp = thisgrp;
})
```

```css
.fav {
  height: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

.markit {
  background-color: coral;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group-456 fav count-2"></div>
<div class="group-456 fav count-1"></div>
<div class="group-456 fav count-3"></div>

<div class="group-143 fav count-4"></div>
<div class="group-143 fav count-2"></div>
<div class="group-143 fav count-1"></div>

<div class="group-855 fav count-4"></div>
<div class="group-855 fav count-2"></div>
<div class="group-855 fav count-1"></div>

<div class="group-616 fav count-4"></div>
<div class="group-616 fav count-2"></div>
<div class="group-616 fav count-1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can group them together using `unique` and `map`. And the first element in each group is `bold`:

```js
//remove other class names
$('.fav').removeClass(function(index, className) {
  return className.replace(/^group-[\d]/, '');
});

// Get all the classes
var classes = $('[class^=group]').map(function() {
  return $(this).attr('class');
});

// Filter only unique ones
var uniqueClasses = $.unique(classes);

// Now group them
$(uniqueClasses).each(function(i, v) {
  $('.' + v).wrapAll('<div class="parent-' + i + '"></div>');
  $('.parent-' + i + ' div:first').addClass('bold');
});
```

```css
.parent-0 {
  background: orange;
  padding: 10px;
}

.parent-1 {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.parent-2 {
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.parent-3 {
  background: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.bold {
  color: #FFF !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group-456 fav count-2">456</div>
<div class="group-456 fav count-1">456</div>
<div class="group-456 fav count-3">456</div>

<div class="group-143 fav count-4">143</div>
<div class="group-143 fav count-2">143</div>
<div class="group-143 fav count-1">143</div>

<div class="group-855 fav count-4">855</div>
<div class="group-855 fav count-2">855</div>
<div class="group-855 fav count-1">855</div>

<div class="group-616 fav count-4">616</div>
<div class="group-616 fav count-2">616</div>
<div class="group-616 fav count-1">616</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var prevclass = '';
$('div').each(function(){
    var newClass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0];
    if(newClass!=prevclass){
      prevclass = newClass;
      console.log(newClass);
    }
});

$('.fav').first().css({background: 'lightcoral'});
```

```css
div{ width:100%; height:20px;border:1px solid; margin:1px 0px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group-456 fav count-2"></div>
<div class="group-456 fav count-1"></div>
<div class="group-456 fav count-3"></div>

<div class="group-143 fav count-4"></div>
<div class="group-143 fav count-2"></div>
<div class="group-143 fav count-1"></div>

<div class="group-855 fav count-4"></div>
<div class="group-855 fav count-2"></div>
<div class="group-855 fav count-1"></div>

<div class="group-616 fav count-4"></div>
<div class="group-616 fav count-2"></div>
<div class="group-616 fav count-1"></div>
```

Comment: Since when the groups are ordered? The question was stating that: "The thing is that they also should stay mixed as they are."

Answer (score 0):

```
var classes = [];
var source = document.querySelectorAll('.fav');

function wrapElements(src, reference, wrapper){
    src.forEach(function(e){
        var elementClasses = e.getAttribute('class').split(" ");
        elementClasses.forEach(function(className){
            if(className.indexOf(reference) !== -1 && classes.indexOf(className) === -1){
                classes.push(className);
            }
        });
    });

    $.each(classes, function(index, value){
        // do whatever you want with the new groups. e.g. group them by class name in a section element:
        $('.' + value).wrapAll('<div class="section">');
    });
}

wrapElements(source, "group-");
```

Comment: You can easily call it with different source elements and custom attribute selector.

Comment: Hey n1kkou, great answer. What would I need to do to not wrap them and leave them mixed up as they are and just apply some css to the first item of each group?