# get jquery class name starting with some letter

Tags: jquery, each, classname

I have an html like this i need to get the class name starting with some letter like 'border_'

```
<div class="box selected border_red"></div>

<div class="box selected border_blue"></div>

<div class="box border_pink inactive"></div>

<div class="box selected border_green"></div>

<div class="box border_grey inactive"></div>

jquery

$('.box').each(function(){

})
```

Out put needed

```
border_red

border_blue

border_pink

border_green

border_grey
```

Comment: Please don't forget to mark any answer that helps you as an accepted answer, by clicking the checkmark at the left top of the answer

Answer (score 2):

```js
var check = "border_"; 
$('div.box[class*="border_"]').each(function () {    
        // Get array of class names   
        var cls = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');       
        for (var i = 0; i < cls.length; i++) {
            // Iterate over the class and log it if it matches
            if (cls[i].indexOf(check) > -1) {        
                console.log(cls[i].slice(0, cls[i].length));
            }       
        }    
    });
```

```css
.box{
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box selected border_red"></div>

<div class="box selected border_blue"></div>

<div class="box border_pink inactive"></div>

<div class="box selected border_green"></div>

<div class="box border_grey inactive"></div>
```

Inspired by this Question: [JQuery get the rest of the element's class name that starts with string “whatever-”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159121/jquery-get-the-rest-of-the-elements-class-name-that-starts-with-string-whateve)

Answer (score 1):

Collect them all by filtering out the ones that don't match

```
var classes = [];
$('.box').each(function() {
    classes = classes
        .concat(
            $(this).attr("class")
              .split(' ')
              .filter(function(cls) {cls.indexOf('border_') === 0})
         );
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like a fairly simple version, just using arrays, map and a nice regex try this;

```
var borders = 
  $(".box")
    .toArray()
    .map( function(el) {
      return el.className.match( /\b(border_[a-z0-9]+)\b/gi )[0];
    });

// "borders" is an array
console.log( borders );
```

---

You could also decide to change `.map()` to a `.each()` and then do some jQuery work inside of the loop with the `el.className.match()` result :)

```
$(".box")
  .each( function(key,el) {
    $(el).text( el.className.match( /\b(border_[a-z0-9]+)\b/gi )[0] );
  });
```

[JSFiddle with results, here](https://jsfiddle.net/simeydotme/30590wzb/)